# How to pass the element that triggered an event into a function in React?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Inside my React function component, I have a code that looks like this:

[image]

How to pass the FontAwesomeIcon element as a parameter into markATaskAsDone?
I tried to pass in 'this' but got an error that says [image]

I also tried to cast this as a JSX.Element before passing it into markATaskAsDone but still get the same error.

Comment: Provide your code here, so we won't guess what is going on there. Also, I guess your question is "not how to pass to function, but to make some effect, like "mark a task as done", so, give us more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways how this can be approached.

The first one is by handling events without parameter. The second one can be done with passing React Event Object.

`<FontAwesomeIcon icon=(faCircleCheck} onClick={()=>{markATaskAsDone }} />`

vs
`<FontAwesomeIcon icon=(faCircleCheck} onClick={(event)=>{markATaskAsDone (event)}} />`

Personally, I would just onClick function, where you would update some states depending on the state you may change rendered HTML.

```
const [isDone, setIsDone]
const markATaskAsDone = () => {
  setIsDone(!isDone)
}

return <FontAwesomeIcon icon=(isDone ? faCheck : faCircleCheck} onClick={()=>{markATaskAsDone ()}} />
```

Also, this may be simplified just by setting the state right from the onClick action.

**EDIT #1**
In case you need to pass the event do it this way...

```
const markATaskAsDone = (event) => {
  console.log(event)
}

return <FontAwesomeIcon icon=(isDone ? faCheck : faCircleCheck} onClick={(event)=>{markATaskAsDone (event)}} />
```

Comment: The arrow function in `onClick` is completely redundant here. You can just `onClick={markATaskAsDone}`.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the event like this

```
<FontAwesomeIcon icon={faCircleCheck} onClick={(e) => markTaskAsDone(e)} />

const markTaskAsDone = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();   
};
```